# Meta tags are updating dynamically and showing in local view source but not on live view source in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api, meta-tags

Meta tags are updating dynamically and showing in the local view source but not on the live view source in angular.  What should I do so that it can be shown in live view source too on the server or a better solution?  is there any thing need to do on server ? any help will be appreciated.

```
 getSinglePostInfo(id){
    this.postService.getSinglePostInfo(id).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data,  'oppa')
      setTimeout(()=> {
        this.metaTagService.updateTag({ property: 'og:title', content:  data['data'].description  });
        this.metaTagService.updateTag({ property: 'og:url', content: ' this.url + data['data'].id });
        this.metaTagService.updateTag( { property: 'og:description', content:data['data'].description });
      },3000)
     
    })
  }
```

I have tried calling meta tag update inside API call by getting only those data which is required its working fine locally and updating, showing in view source too but not on live URL.

Its also shows that it is updated in elements header but not showing update in view source on live.

Comment: can you share live url ? did u make sure that after 3 sec this code runs and page is loaded before that ?

Comment: Yes it working after 3 second and can also work without set timeout too in local but not working for live. working on npm run dev:ssr locally but not on npm run build:ssr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find solution and its working now properly. I have added async ,await but the main reason was there was use of promise.all() in my same page where other unnecessary api was calling , so when I removed promise.all() , its start updating and showing in view source on live.

```
 async getSinglePostMetaData(id){
    await this.postService.getSinglePostMetaData(id).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data.data,  'oppa')
         this.metaTagService.updateTag({ property: 'og:title', content:  data.data.description });
         this.metaTagService.updateTag({ property: 'og:url', content:  this.url + data.data.id  });
         this.metaTagService.updateTag( { property:'og:image', content: img_path});
         this.metaTagService.updateTag( { property: 'og:description', content:data.data.description });
    
    })
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).